# How to sign with RSASSA-PSS in Java correctly?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, signature

I need to code this openssl-sign-instruction in java.

> openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -out "signaturefile".sig -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -sign "privatekey".pem "file2sign"

This instruction comes from Bundeszentralamt für Steuern (BZSt) - ELMA-File-Upload.

> Bitte stellen Sie die Signaturerstellung daher auf RSASSA-PSS mit folgenden Parametern um:
>
> Hashverfahren: SHA-256
>
> Mask Generation Function: MGF1 mit SHA-256 Länge des Salts: 32 Byte Trailer Field: 0xBC

I've already tried different signature algorithms (with and without bouncycastle) but didn't get the same signature-result as with openssl.

This is what I'm doing.

```
public class SignTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        Signature signatureSHA256Java = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS");
        signatureSHA256Java.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, 32, 1));

        signatureSHA256Java.initSign(KeyManagerHelper.getPrivateKeyFromKeyStore("privatekey"));
        signatureSHA256Java.update(byteArray);
        byte[] signSHA256Java = signatureSHA256Java.sign();

        // after that I compare the Java-sign-bytearry with the openssl one
        System.out.println("signSHA256Java == signSHA256Openssl:\n" + Arrays.equals(signSHA256Java, signSHA256Openssl));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a randomized signature so you're not supposed to get the same result.

Comment: Ok that makes sence. I didn't realized it. How can I verify my Java-Signature with openssl? I suppose something like "openssl dgst -sha256 -verify ..."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I edited my question with the correct algorithm to create the signature with java bouncycastle.

```
Signature signatureSHA256Java = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS");
signatureSHA256Java.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, 32, 1));
```

You can verify the java generated signature with openssl like that

> openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -verify "publickey".pem -signature "signaturefile".sig "file2sign"

Comment: Hair loss = 5 on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for actually answering your own question after finding the answer yourself